# Como almacenar mi localstorage en mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, local-storage

tengo una aplicación web (Tienda), la cual mis productos se almacenan en mi localStorage, pero ahora necesito ese json que se guarda en mi localstore, guardarlo en una tabla en mi base de datos MySQL. Como puedo hacerlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Saludos, bienviedo a SOes, te dejo una lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Muchachos, el usuario es nuevo, no ha realizado ni el recorrido, antes de ponerle un voto negativo, un comentario para guiarlo por favor. Gracias por su comprensión.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio, también lee [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida ñ. Recuerda que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/480455/edit) tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario

Comment: Lastimosamente muchos otros usuario con el privilegio de cerrar preguntas solo saben cerrar preguntas y no guían al usuario a elaborar una buena pregunta. Editando tu pregunta puede que sea reabierta